# Change the default app in "Open with" dialog

Tags: default-applications

I have at one point chosen Truedialer as the default app for opening contacts.

I would now like to set Google Contacts as the default app.

I have cleared the `Launch by default` setting for Truedialer.

However, when I click on a contact (found using searchbar) I get a dialog stating

```
Open with View contact
                  [JUST ONCE] [ALWAYS]
Use a different app
Contacts
```

[image: Open with dialog]

(`View contact` is the Truedialer app, `Contacts` is the Google Contacts app)

Now, I can choose `View contact` as `ALWAYS`, but I *cannot* choose `Contacts` as `ALWAYS`, I can only click it to use it once.

This same dialog shows up every time, no matter how many times I search for a contact. It only gives me the option of setting `View contact` as default, never `Contacts`.

How can I set `Contacts` as default?

Comment: The app that is shown at the top, is the app you used the last time to deal with contacts. If you use `Contacts` now then next time `Contacts` is on top and you can tap `Always`. I know, it's a bad design decision.

Comment: @GiantTree unfortunately, that is not the behaviour I get. I have opened the Google Contacts app and then immediately after attempted the above search and select operation. The result is the same. I have also chosen Contacts in the above dialog and then repeated the search and select operation. Still the same behaviour.

Comment: I have the similar issue where I cant not see supported apps in "Use a different app" section that was previously visible. It happens to me after upgrading to Android 6

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a widget.

For me the following worked:

Go to `Settings`->`Apps` and click on the menu button (the three dots in the right top) and select `Reset app preferences`.

This resets a lot of stuff, but I was able to select `Always`for the right app again.